# I can find no contingency of tense here..or may be I am wrong?

Tags: tense, american-english

> "if you liked one piece, we can notify you when new chapters published"

in the sentence above, I cannot find any contingency. It's totally sprawling.

Shouldn't it be like

> "if you like one piece, we can notify you when new chapters publish"

The sentence I mentioned should be narrated in present tense, shouldn't it?

Comment: Or maybe it's just a sort of author's faux pas? You know,at times,they word stuff without any grammar..

Comment: There is a word missing:  "...when new chapters *are* published".

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means: if you liked one piece (in the past) we can notify you when new chapters are published. (It is a 'real conditional'.)

Still some context would make it more clear.

This sentence is not an 'unreal conditional' because otherwise it would be like this:

> If you liked one piece we would notify you when new chapters were
>   published.